# Android app rings for old notifications

Tags: bug, notifications, android-app

Whenever I connect my tablet to a wifi, the SO Android app seems to iterate through the SO notifications I got while the device was not connected to the Internet.

The problem is, even though I have read a notification already on the desktop browser, the app shortly shows a status bar notification for that, and then hides it again.

This does not matter when I have toggled off vibration and ring tone for the app's notification, but when those are enabled, the device performs some weird vibrating/ringing for quite some seconds depending on how active I was while the device was offline.

Comment: yeah I have noticed this issue.

Comment: This is kind of a recurring bug in most android apps (Twitter and Facebook do it too), it's been on my to-do list for a while but I'll see what I can do.